# ASP System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net

What should be the problem here?

```
MailAddress msgFrom = new MailAddress("donotreply@mydomain.com", "Friendly Name");
```

This doesn't work. The email is still the one that displays on recipient's inbox.

The sender's name should be displayed as "Friendly Name" instead of donotreply@mydomain.com on the recipient's inbox

Comment: Please be more specific. Exactly what 
"doesn't work"?

Comment: The sender's name should be displayed as "Friendly Name" instead of donotreply@mydomain.com on the recipient's inbox

Answer (score 0):

it seems, there is no problem with your code.

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane Clayton");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

However, you can try this example: [MailAddress.DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.displayname.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the recipient's email box already have the email you sent before, check the recipient's contact details to check if the sender is in the contact, sometimes it's the reason.

Also you can check the header(also called the original message) of the email body, there should be a line like this `From: Friendly Name <donotreply@mydomain.com>`, if you find this, you need to do nothing about the code, it's worked

Or try to send to the another email address which have no emails from the sender.